# Error : {"message":"sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: near \"id\": syntax error","code":5}

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have a object below and i want to save it to a sqlite database but I kept getting the error. below is the snippet of the object that I want to save. I already used JSON.Stringify but still i cant get the correct answer.

```
[{"id":0,"inputName":"Seeds","cost":"100"},
{"id":2,"inputName":"Chemicals(Insecticide,Pesticide,Fungicide)","cost":"100"},
{"id":0,"inputName":"ASample","cost":"100"}]
```

Here is my sample insert query code

```
    this.storeInput = JSON.stringify(this.input);
    this.storeLabor = JSON.stringify(this.labor);
    this.storeAdmin = JSON.stringify(this.admin);
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ionicdb.db',
      location: 'default'
        }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          db.executeSql('INSERT INTO `carrots_expenses`(`input`, `labor`, `admin`) VALUES("'+this.storeInput+'","'+this.storeLabor+'","'+this.storeAdmin+'")', {})

            }).catch(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)))
```

This is how I created the table

```
db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carrots_expenses(`rowid` int auto_increment primary key, `input` JSON DEFAULT NULL, `labor` JSON DEFAULT NULL, `admin` JSON DEFAULT NULL)', {})
```

I spend too much time searching for the answer and I can`t find it, I might miss keywords to search for something.

Comment: sqlite3 error code 5 is a "database locked" . Here is what the sqlite doc has to say on the subject https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy.  Possibly there is another connection to the database that has "written" (as with INSERT) but not commited the transaction.You might try "sqlite code 5" as search in this forum.

Comment: Based on my code only one sql is running , i think the value of the object is containing some mistake but still i cant figure out what is the correct answer. or maybe how to store that array of object to sql